# WebView and MutationObserver not working

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm injecting some Javascript inside a WebView that I have no control on. I'm trying to use MutationObserver but it does not notify me when changes happen. Everything works except mutations:

```
(function(){
if(typeof androidControlbarListener !== "undefined"){
    var controlbar = document.getElementsByClassName(\"controlbar\")[0];
    var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(controlbar).display;
    if(displayStyle !== \'none\') {
        androidControlbarListener.controlbarVisible();
        var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true };
        MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                    var currentValue = mutation.target.style.display;
                    //some processing here
                    androidControlbarListener.controlbarChanged();
                });
            });
            observer.observe(controlbar, config);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
})()
```

I use `@JavascriptInterface` for callbacks and `evaluateJavascript` method. 
I never receive calls to `androidControlbarListener`.